# use will-paginate with multiple consult

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use will_pagination in my project, seems very easy, but I have this consult to show a list of idea...

```
@ideas= current_company.ideas.find_all_by_status_and_creator_id('editable', current_user.id) +
      current_company.ideas.find_all_by_status('valid') + 
      current_company.ideas.find_all_by_status_and_creator_id('purchable', !current_user.id)
```

so I modified it like this, to use the paginate

```
current_company.ideas.where(:status => ['editable', 'valid'], :creator_id=> current_user.id).paginate ....
```

but how I include the last condition?

If I include status "purchable" in the array, How to do to take the other user distint of current_user?

any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, i believe you have to create a `where` string.

```
current_company.ideas.where(
"
  (status IN ('editable', 'valid') AND creator_id = ?) 
  AND 
  (status = 'purchable' AND creator_id <> ?) 
", 
current_user.id, !current_user.id).paginate...
```

Beware that maybe you will have to put the table name before the attributes like `ideas.status`.